# Numpy decompress image to get original pixel size

Tags: image, numpy, compression, svd

I've read in an image from a jpg and converted to a numpy array. I've compressed the image, and now need to write a new function to return the number of "equivalent pixels" used by the compressed (truncated SVD) representation.

```
def compress_image(I, k):

    U, s, V = svd(I, full_matrices=False)
    U= U[:,:k]
    V= np.dot(np.diag(s[:k]),V[:k,:])
    return (s, U, V)
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked:

```
def size_compressed_image(Sigma, Uk, VkT):
    byte=8 #constant
    m,k=Uk.shape
    k2,n=VkT.shape
    assert k ==k2
    return byte* (m*k+k+k*n)
```